# View added items on reopening the app? (Java - Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm a beginner in android development.
I've been trying to build a To-Do list app.
My app is capable of accepting data and displaying them. (Image below)
[image: app screenshot]

As of now when i reopen the app these added items get reset leaving the list blank.
The help i need is, how do i keep these added items as it is when i reopen the app.
I know how to use SharedPreference concept for textView and EditTexts. But its just that I don't know how i apply it in recyclerViews.
Hope someones willing to guide me through this.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use some sort of a database for this, as you add an item you also save it inside the database of choice, and whenever you open the app check at the start if the database is not empty and then display the ones available if any.

When you open the app check for your `SharedPreference` and see if the list is not empty, get it and pass it along to the `Adapter` of the `RecyclerView`

Examples of databases:
Realm,
Firebase Firestore or Firebase Realtime database,
SharedPreference (though this is preferred to be used for cache and not big data),
Room,
SQLite.

Answer (score 2):

Reading you're question, I have a feeling you are still not aware of concepts like data persistence and databases, please correct me if I'm wrong, You might have to read a bit about SQLite Database which is the default database used in android devices! Please read the android Docs to get a better idea about it: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite

I will give a general idea of the flow you have to follow to achieve this:

1. You might want to create the data class, that will hold all the necessary data for the item. in your case, it will be used to hold todo items. It must have an ID field that will be used to uniquely identify it. other fields include the title, date, etc. I assume you might have already created it for this app. Something like this:

```
class TodoItem{
        long id;
        String name;
        long date;

        public TodoItem() {
        }

        public TodoItem(long id, String name, long data) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.date = data;
        }

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public long getDate() {
            return date;
        }

        public void setDate(long date) {
            this.date = date;
        }
    }
```

2. second step is to create the view that will display the data on the screen, which you have already created for the app.
3. the third and most important step is Data persistence, you need to create a database where all the data must be added and later retrieved, whenever it is required. We will use SQL for this purpose!

First, create an SQL Helper class:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MY_DATABASE";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "TODO_TABLE";
    public static final String TODO_COLUMN_ID = "ID";
    public static final String TODO_COLUMN_NAME = "NAME";
    public static final String TODO_COLUMN_DATE = "DATE";
    private HashMap hp;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                + TODO_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                + TODO_COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, "
                + TODO_COLUMN_DATE + " LONG);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Now in the above class add 2 functions one to insert an item and one to get all the items (using a cursor) like so:

inserting an element is as simple as creating a [Content Values](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues) Object and calling the insert function on the database.

```
public boolean insertItem(String title, long date) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(TODO_COLUMN_NAME, title);
    contentValues.put(TODO_COLUMN_DATE, date);
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    return true;
}
```

to get a list of all items we use a cursor to query the database and create a list of todo items that are returned by the function.

```
public ArrayList<TodoItem> getAllItems() {
    ArrayList<TodoItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "  + TABLE_NAME, null);
    res.moveToFirst();
    while (!res.isAfterLast()) {
        TodoItem todoItem  = new TodoItem();
        todoItem.setId(res.getLong(res.getColumnIndex(TODO_COLUMN_ID)));
        todoItem.setName(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(TODO_COLUMN_NAME)));
        todoItem.setDate(res.getLong(res.getColumnIndex(TODO_COLUMN_DATE)));
        items.add(todoItem);
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return items;
}
```

so now in the activity you just have to create an object of the DBhelper class and whenever you want to insert an object into the database just call the insert function, and later whenever the activity is started again call the getAllItems() function of the DBHelper class to get a list of all the todo items that can be displayed to the user! like so -

```
DBHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

databaseHelper.insertItem("buy groceries", System.currentTimeMillis()); // insert an item

ArrayList<TodoItem> items = databaseHelper.getAllItems(); // get a list of all items
```

Answer (score 0):

The added items donot get saved if you just add them to the recyclerview. You must save the data in a database and then retrieve it from there when your app starts. Room is an android library provided by android for storing data using SQLite, Room is a wrapper for SQLite database. You can get more information about the Room library here:

[link](http://%20%20%20%20https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room)